# Tkinter entry.get() not returning value

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, txt

I have a few tkinter class and def, started with an entry that will paste the value in order to change the content of a specific line of txt when I click a tkinter button.

Entry part:

```
class horizontal():
  def entry():
    global x
    text=tk.Entry(root)
    text.grid(row = y ,column = x);x+=1
```

The problem is, the text.get() is not able to get any information from the entry box to change the content no matter how I try, I tried removing it from the current class, global variable..etc but nothing work. Here is the txt read and replace part:

```
class readandwrite:
def typein(h):
    print("**********h is ",h)
    with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\Customer.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

    print('text get is',text.get())  
    data[h-1] = "11-201\n"#text.get()

    with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\Customer.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.writelines(data)
```

I've tried printing out what it got like what you see from above but I got nothing, it just said  *text get is* and that's it. Any ideas where I went wrong? I've tried looking at other question but couldn't find anything. Thank you!

Edit: I'm making a small reproduction of what happened but it seem to work just fine and give out the value like normal, here's what I did, I've included in different class too to prove that it doesn't get affected

```
class notinrturn:
def labels():
    l = tk.Label(window, bg='white', width=20, text='empty')
    l.pack()
class huhuhu:
def weird():
    global text
    if var.get() ==1:
        print(text.get())
 class defentry:
def entry():
    global x
    global text
    text=tk.Entry(window)
    text.pack()
  notinrturn.labels()        
  defentry.entry()

  var=tk.IntVar()
  c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Python',variable=var, 
  onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=huhuhu.weird)
  c1.pack()

  window.mainloop()
```

The above code work just fine and print value as expected but not like the others :(
[image]

I'll include the github link in case there's any information that you guys need, I'm sorry for not providing enough, I'm afraid it might be too long: https://github.com/StandardV/Deadline-Tracing

Comment: The `text` inside `entry()` is a *local variable* that ceases to exist as soon as the function finishes, leaving you with no way to access the Entry.  I can't tell what the `text` inside `typein()` is referring to (you didn't include its definition), but it's certainly not that Entry.

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, thank you for your recommendation. My current script look bigger but in summary, it's just like the above code that I just edited exclude some loop and calculation. I'll try to look back at the program map right now to see if I did it wrong somewhere but overall, I think it's the same. Thank you again

Comment: Often, the symptoms you report are because you're calling `get` before the user has entered  any data. You might try adding a print statement to see if it's happening before or after you  type in the widget.

Answer (score -1):

> Tkinter entry.get() not returning value.

There are so many ways to workaround.

The problem can be fix.

- Move `Label` widget before `labels()` function. This way you can
  called `Label` widget anywhere.
- On line 16, comment out `#global text`.
- On line 19, add `notinrturn.l.config(text=text.get())`. This way you
  can get updating.
- On line 23, comment out `#global x`.
- On line 29, correct way to execute the script by using `if __name__== '__main__':`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('150x120')

class notinrturn:
    l = tk.Label(window, bg='white', width=20, text='empty')
    l.pack()
    def labels():
        notinrturn.l.config(text='empty')
         
        
class huhuhu:
    def weird():
        #global text
        if var.get() == 1:
            print(text.get())
            notinrturn.l.config(text=text.get())
            
class defentry:
    def entry():
        #global x
        global text
        text = tk.Entry(window)
        text.pack()


if __name__== '__main__':        
    notinrturn.labels()        
    defentry.entry()

    var=tk.IntVar()
     
    c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Python',variable=var, 
    onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=huhuhu.weird)
    c1.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]